# Issue with parallel column height using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have four divs/columns with varying amounts of text inside them. Using flexbox I assumed that I would be able to size all the columns to the largest div size, but from the codepen included you should see that the the columns all appear with varying heights.

My end goal is to have them all the same height, yet they should squeeze and stretch in unison when the page is resized, at the halfway point the columns will rearrange themselves in a 2 x 2 grid, and at mobile size all divs are stacked one on top of the other. This part works as expected, but the 4 divs are still of varying sizes.

HTML:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<div class="table-layout">
  <div class="table-cell row">

    <div class="flexboxContainer">

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default summary-panel" style="background: green; color: white;">
          <div class="panel-body flexboxContent">

            <div  class="chartContainer">

              <div class="table-layout">
                <div class="table-cell row">
                  <h1>0</h1>
                  <span style="font-size: 14px">blah blah blah blah</span>
                </div>
                <div class="table-cell row">
                  <span style="font-size: 64px; opacity: 0.3"></span>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default summary-panel" style="background: green; color: white;">
          <div class="panel-body flexboxContent">

            <div class="chartContainer">

              <div class="table-layout">
                <div class="table-cell row">
                  <h1>0</h1>
                  <span style="font-size: 14px">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span>
                </div>
                <div class="table-cell row">
                  <span style="font-size: 64px; opacity: 0.3"></span>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default summary-panel" style="background: green; color: white;">
          <div class="panel-body flexboxContent">

            <div  class="chartContainer">

              <div class="table-layout">
                <div class="table-cell row">
                  <h1>0</h1>
                  <span style="font-size: 14px">blah blah blah blah</span>
                </div>
                <div class="table-cell row">
                  <span style="font-size: 64px; opacity: 0.3"></span>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default summary-panel" style="background: green; color: white;">
          <div class="panel-body flexboxContent">

            <div class="chartContainer">

              <div class="table-layout">
                <div class="table-cell row">
                  <h1>0</h1>
                  <span style="font-size: 14px">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span>
                </div>
                <div class="table-cell row">
                  <span style="font-size: 64px; opacity: 0.3"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i></span>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.flexboxContainer {
  display: flex;
  border: solid red;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexboxContent {
  border: solid black;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.table-layout {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}

.table-layout .table-cell {
  display:table-cell;
}

.chartContainer {
    position: relative;
}
```

Codepen example:
https://codepen.io/synchrosion/pen/yopxGY

I have the flexbox container and flexbox content highlighted with a border for clarity, and I am trying to have all my flexbox content boxes at the same height without specifying a fixed min or max height.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You're using *way* too much markup.

Comment: I was just simplifying it from a much more complex piece of code, I wanted to keep some of the extra divs within divs just incase they proved to be the issue with why flexbox wasn't equalling out my div heights

Comment: Extraneous markup makes using flexbox correctly much more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add to your css:

```
    .panel-default {
         height: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a fiddle for your question, you must set height 100% for your flexboxContent

```
jsfiddle.net/ybtnhzna
```